# Webbrowser login - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Anyone has any idea what is the problem?
If I click button9 then I get an application error.

Button9 code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("Value", Text1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("Value", Text2.Text)

For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If element.GetAttribute("name") = "login" Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next

WaitForPageLoad()
If Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("abc") Then
    MsgBox("E-mail címed nem ismerhető fel.")
Else
    MsgBox("Bejelentkeztél.")
End If
```

Debug:
http://pastebin.com/G21ULFqF

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the web-application you're using is buggy, anyway, you can compare the two HTTP requests using a tool like Fiddler to see what the difference is between the request your application is making vs. what any other browser does.

Comment: It's working on my computer, but my client has problem with that button.

Comment: Are you referencing any 3rd party dlls in your project that maybe aren't being copied locally and therefore aren't given to you client? Does the client get an error in their application or system logs in the windows event viewer? Usually those errors gives a clearer understanding of the problem. If no to both of those questions, you could always try writing to a log file after every line in the `Button9` code and see exactly which line causes the problem. My guess is that its dying at the `WaitForPageLoad()` line. What is happening in that sub?